# Thunderbird bulk save attachments from many emails

Tags: attachments, bulk

in older versions of TB we had attachment extractor, which had many useful functions.
Now as far as I know its not compatible with TB 78.7.0 (32bit).

Is thare a way either directly from TB or with add-on to save attachments from few emails with one command/function?

Win7 64bit / TB 78.7.0(32bit).

Comment: Good question, though I only know of a workaround: select multiple messages and *Save as...*, which saves the batch of messages, each with it's attachment, as a file.